# Fetching API with requests.Session

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wrote a script that parses API on schedule (Tuesday-Saturday), downloading everything for the previous day.

---

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date, timedelta

# # This is what I'd normally use, but since there would be no data today, 
# # I assign specific date myself 
# DATE = (date.today() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
DATE = "2020-10-23"
URL = "https://spending.gov.ua/portal-api/v2/api/transactions/page/" 


def fetch(session, params):
    next_page, last_page = 0, 0
    while next_page <= last_page:
        params["page"] = next_page
        data = session.get(URL, params=params).json()
        yield pd.json_normalize(data.get("transactions"))\
                .assign(page=params.get("page"))
        next_page, last_page = next_page+1, data["count"] // data["pageSize"]
                
        
def fetch_all():
    with requests.Session() as session:
        params = {"page": 0, "pageSize": 100, "startdate": DATE, "enddate": DATE}
        yield from fetch(session, params)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = fetch_all()
    pd.concat(data).to_csv(f"data/{DATE}.csv", index=False)
```

---

Here I’m wondering about a couple of things.

*Firstly*, if I’m using `requests.Session` correctly.

I read in the documentation that:

> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. ... So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase.

I'm not sure whether that's the case here as I didn't notice any changes in the performance.

*Secondly*, if splitting code into two functions instead of one was a good idea.

Here I thought that it would be easier to maintain -- the underlying function `fetch` doesn't change while `fetch_all` potentially could. For example, I could feed a range of dates instead of a singe date, changing `fetch_all` to:

```py
def fetch_all(date_range):
    with requests.Session() as session:
        for date in date_range:
            params = {"page": 0, "pageSize": 100, "startdate": date, "enddate": date}
            yield from fetch(session, params)
```

Also, the `yield` and `yield from` -- could've used `.append` and returned a list instead. Not sure which approach is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here I’m wondering about a couple of things.
>
> *Firstly*, if I’m using `requests.Session` correctly.

Yes, you are. In [one of my other reviews](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/236925), using `requests.Session` in the same way for iterating over a paginated API almost halved the total execution time.

I did some quick testing by downloading the last 7 pages (pages 1625-1631) for "2020-10-23" and it did marginally better than making requests with `requests.get`:

- `requests.get`: 23.2 seconds
- `requests.Session`: 17.7 seconds

> *Secondly*, if splitting code into two functions instead of one was a good idea.

I think it's fine to have it split into two functions. That said, I do have some comments about the responsibilities and interface of `fetch` and how to better take advantage of your usages of `yield` and `yield from` down below.

---

Overall the code looks clean and is easy to read. Here's how I think it can be improved:

- I think all the low-level details of how to issue requests to the API should be abstracted away from the caller of `fetch`. That is, `fetch`'s function signature should look something like this:

  ```python
  def fetch(
      session: requests.Session,
      start_date: date,
      end_date: date,
      starting_page: int = 0,
      page_size: int = 100,
  ) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
      pass
  ```

  So now creating an appropriate `params` would be `fetch`'s responsibility, not `fetch_all`'s. Notice also that `start_date` and `end_date` are of type `datetime.date`, not `str`. Similarly, `fetch_all` should not have to be concerned with what date string serialization format the API accepts; this is `fetch`'s responsibility.
- Within `fetch`, instead of maintaining variables `next_page` and `last_page` on each request, I think it would be better to calculate the total number of pages (n) only once with the first request (page k), then use a for loop for pages k+1..n-1:

  ```python
  def to_dataframe(json_data: Dict[str, Any], page: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
      return pd.json_normalize(json_data["transactions"]).assign(page=page)


  def fetch(
      session: requests.Session,
      start_date: date,
      end_date: date,
      starting_page: int = 0,
      page_size: int = 100,
  ) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
      params = {
          "startdate": start_date.isoformat(),
          "enddate": end_date.isoformat(),
          "page": starting_page,
          "pageSize": page_size,
      }

      data = session.get(URL, params=params).json()
      page_count = math.ceil(data["count"] / data["pageSize"])
      last_page = page_count - 1
      if starting_page > last_page:
          return
      print(f"{starting_page} / {last_page}")
      yield to_dataframe(data, starting_page)

      for page in range(starting_page + 1, page_count):
          params["page"] = page
          data = session.get(URL, params=params).json()
          print(f"{page} / {last_page}")
          yield to_dataframe(data, page)
  ```

  The tradeoff here is that there's a small duplication of code because the first request is handled a little differently, but now we've delegated responsibility of page number iteration to the for loop.
- I recommend adding an [event hook](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/advanced/#event-hooks) to the `session` object so that it always calls `raise_for_status()` on the response object. This ensures that all requests made with the session raise `requests.HTTPError` if the server gives us a 4xx or 5xx response, and prevents us from converting an error response's `.json()` data into a dataframe:

  ```python
  session.hooks["response"].append(
      lambda r, *args, **kwargs: r.raise_for_status()
  )
  ```
- Currently the program is combining all dataframes in memory before exporting it to a CSV file. To take advantage of `fetch_all` being an `Iterator[pd.DataFrame]`, I think it would be better to write each dataframe to the CSV immediately, so we don't need to hold it in memory any longer than necessary:

  ```python
  output_path = Path(f"data/{DATE}.csv")
  output_path.unlink(missing_ok=True)
  data = fetch_all()
  for i, dataframe in enumerate(data):
      write_header = True if i == 0 else False
      dataframe.to_csv(
          output_path, header=write_header, index=False, mode="a"
      )
  ```

---

Refactored version:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import math
from datetime import date, timedelta
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any, Dict, Iterator

import pandas as pd  # type: ignore
import requests

# # This is what I'd normally use, but since there would be no data today,
# # I assign specific date myself
# DATE = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)
DATE = date.fromisoformat("2020-10-23")
URL = "https://spending.gov.ua/portal-api/v2/api/transactions/page/"


def to_dataframe(json_data: Dict[str, Any], page: int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return pd.json_normalize(json_data["transactions"]).assign(page=page)


def fetch(
    session: requests.Session,
    start_date: date,
    end_date: date,
    starting_page: int = 0,
    page_size: int = 100,
) -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    params = {
        "startdate": start_date.isoformat(),
        "enddate": end_date.isoformat(),
        "page": starting_page,
        "pageSize": page_size,
    }

    data = session.get(URL, params=params).json()
    page_count = math.ceil(data["count"] / data["pageSize"])
    last_page = page_count - 1
    if starting_page > last_page:
        return
    print(f"{starting_page} / {last_page}")
    yield to_dataframe(data, starting_page)

    for page in range(starting_page + 1, page_count):
        params["page"] = page
        data = session.get(URL, params=params).json()
        print(f"{page} / {last_page}")
        yield to_dataframe(data, page)


def fetch_all() -> Iterator[pd.DataFrame]:
    with requests.Session() as session:
        session.hooks["response"].append(
            lambda r, *args, **kwargs: r.raise_for_status()
        )
        yield from fetch(session, start_date=DATE, end_date=DATE)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    output_path = Path(f"data/{DATE}.csv")
    output_path.unlink(missing_ok=True)
    data = fetch_all()
    for i, dataframe in enumerate(data):
        write_header = True if i == 0 else False
        dataframe.to_csv(
            output_path, header=write_header, index=False, mode="a"
        )
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. I learnt a lot!

Comment: Though I intentionally used while loop to avoid code duplication in fetch function. But I agree that  your approach is more explicit, so I’ll use it instead. Thanks once again.